# SQL Sum top 5 rows for each team

Tags: mysql

I got help with this SQL-question below to sum up top 5 lenght for each team. The problem for me now seems that SQL is randomly selecting 5 of the for eg 7 rows in the database for team 25, not the top 5. Anyone has any ideas for me? Would be much appriciated!

```
select team, sum(length) as totalScore 
from 
(
    SELECT
        t.*,
        @num_in_group:=case when @team!=team then @num_in_group:=0 else @num_in_group:=@num_in_group+1 end as num_in_group,
        @team:=team as t
    FROM reg_catches t, (select @team:=-1, @num_in_group:=0) init
    ORDER BY team asc
) sub
WHERE
    sub.num_in_group <= 4 and
    competition = 16    and
    team = 25 
GROUP BY team
ORDER BY totalScore DESC;
```

Table

```
team length competition
----------------------
26   70       16
25   70       16
25   95       16
25   98       16
25   100      16
25   100      16
25   100      16
25   122      16
```

Wanted output:

```
team totalScore
---- -----------
25  520
26  70
```

Best regards,
Christian

Comment: No primary key in the table?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Why would a primary key help here on top of the data we already have?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen You wrote it in your own answer: "some other column to break the tie".

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Good call...sadly MySQL is just not very good at this sort of query.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen well MySQL 8 and MariaDB 10.2 support window functions like `ROW_NUMBER()`. A lot of answers should be updated (soon).

Comment: With or without window functions, MySQL's just fine at this kind of query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to get the top 5 rows for each `team`, you could utilise a parameter to rank each team's results:

```
SELECT *, 
(@rank := if(@team = team, @rank + 1, if(@team := team, 1, 1))) as rank 
FROM (SELECT * from reg_catches order by team, length desc) ordered
HAVING rank <= 5
ORDER BY team, rank asc
```

Which would produce the following: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6042ae/1

```
| team | length | competition | rank |
+------+--------+-------------+------+
|  25  |   99   |     16      |   1  |
|  25  |   98   |     16      |   2  |
|  25  |   77   |     16      |   3  |
|  25  |   76   |     16      |   4  |
|  25  |   73   |     16      |   5  |
|  26  |   96   |     16      |   1  |
|  26  |   88   |     16      |   2  |
|  26  |   87   |     16      |   3  |
|  26  |   83   |     16      |   4  |
|  26  |   79   |     16      |   5  |
```

You could then, if required, wrap that query in a simple aggregation/group to get the total of the top 5 for each team

```
SELECT team, sum(length) as 'total score' FROM
(SELECT *, 
(@rank := if(@team = team, @rank + 1, if(@team := team, 1, 1))) as rank 
FROM (SELECT * from reg_catches order by team, length desc) ordered
HAVING rank <= 5
ORDER BY team, rank asc) top5
GROUP BY team
```

As per http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6042ae/2

```
| team  |total score|
+-------+-----------+
|  25   |   423     |
|  26   |   433     |
|  27   |   426     |
```

The usual caveats will apply to parameters, but you can't really 'rank' in MySQL without them.  I also found this very sensitive to initially getting the scores in the right order before applying the parameters.

Whilst this might not be the most polished solution, I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the solution! Now i'm trying to get the sum of top 5 as for for your second suggestion but with an implemented rank number for each team but I can't get that to work.. any ideas?

Wanted output would be something like

rank   team total score
1  25  423
2  26  433
3  27  426

Comment: @ChristianÅvall - just nominate 'rank' in your select, as it's there to use in the query.
For disclosure, the use of attributes in context of things like 'rank' are seen as "unreliable" by folk on here (as in MySQL it can be 'unpredicatable'), but it's the only way of doing it and I'm yet to see it not work).

Answer (score 1):

In your inner query add another ordering clause as

```
 ORDER BY team asc ,length desc
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3e30fb/12)

This will order rows of table first with team and then for each team it will order rows by length column value, so higher value for team will be returned first

Or another way to get you the same results without using variables

```
select a.team, sum(a.length) as totalScore 
from (
select b.*,(
    select count(*) 
    from reg_catches c
    where b.team = c.team
    and b.length < c.length
   ) + 1 rownum
from reg_catches b
) a
where a.rownum <=5
group by a.team
order by totalScore DESC;
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3e30fb/8)

> Make sure to have an index on team and length column to get better performance

Answer (score 1):

Besides any logical problems you have with your current query, there may be other risks in the form of the behavior of MySQL session variables.  MySQL does not guarantee the order in which assignments to session variables will take place in a select statement.  Hence, a query to simulate rank with a partition (your problem) may not be reliable.  But we can still solve the problem by using a correlated subquery to label the top 5 lengths for each team:

```
SELECT
    team,
    SUM(length) AS totalScore
FROM
(
    SELECT
        team,
        length,
        competition,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM reg_catches t2
         WHERE t2.team = t1.team AND t2.length >= t1.length) cnt
    FROM reg_catches t1
) t
WHERE
    cnt <= 5 AND
    competition = 16
GROUP BY
    team
ORDER BY
    team;
```

Note that this query has a limitation should there be ties present.  If you expect ties then we could work around this by using some other column to break the tie.

**Output:**

```
    team    totalScore
1   25      520
2   26      70
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester